# How do I replace all special characters but also keep new lines?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Consider the following:

```
{{- define "testfunc.someYaml" -}}
my/lable.one: sdfsdfsdfdsf
my/lable.two: sdfsdfsdfdsf
{{- end -}}

{{- define "testfunc.replaceSpecialChars" -}}
{{- include "testfunc.someYaml" . | replace "/" "_" | replace "." "_"  -}}
{{- end -}}
```

The template `testfunc.replaceSpecialChars` returns:

```
my_lable_one: sdfsdfsdfdsf
my_lable_two: sdfsdfsdfdsf
```

This does what I want, but I'd prefer to just replace ALL special characters instead of having to keep piping to replace.

I appears `regexReplaceAll "\\W+"` can do this, but I'm not sure how to use it. First it doesn't support `|` from my experimentation with it and this doesn't work:

```
{{- define "testfunc.two" -}}
{{ regexReplaceAll "\\W+" (include "testfunc.one" .) "_" }}
{{- end -}}
```

The above will return this:

```
my_lable_one_sdfsdfsdfdsf_my_lable_two_sdfsdfsdfdsf
```

Is there any way to have regexReplaceAll keep new lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `regexReplaceAll` construction is correct; it will replace any contiguous string of one or more "non-word" characters with underscores, where "word" characters are ASCII letters, digits, and underscore.

Your logic problem here is trying to apply this to the output YAML dictionary.  In principle you could define colon, space, and newline as "not special" and build a more involved regex, but this is a little fragile.  You're also converting not just the keys but also the values, which may not be the output you want.

Possibly the most robust way to approach this is to take the output of your first function; use the underdocumented `fromYaml` function to convert it to a map; and then loop over the resulting keys and values.  So one approach might look like:

```
{{- range $k, $v := include "testfunc.someYaml" . | fromYaml -}}
{{ regexReplaceAll "[^[:alnum]]+" $k "_" }}: {{ $v }}
{{ end }}
```

I've changed the regex slightly (it should convert `foo_..._bar` to `foo_bar` with only one underscore and not three) but also applied it only to the key and not to the value.  You could straightforwardly apply this to the value as well.  The important detail is that the colon, space, and newline that are needed for YAML syntax are not passed through the regex.